# Blinking LED on MSP430 with three conditions

Tags: microcontroller, c, embedded, msp430, launchpad

I was designing a circuit which must satisfy  conditions.

LED2(green) should blink at 2Hz 50% duty cycle

Comment: Not a complete answer, but: time to research the timer/counter options available on your device. Having a low frequency/RTC reference signal of known frequency would help you meet your specification. Using interrupts rather than hard delays is also a good idea.

Comment: this could be done with one-shots, FF's and gates too

Comment: 2 Hz 50% duty cycle... is 1 Hz...

Comment: This is a question and answer site, not for show and tell.  We don't care what you did on your summer vacation either.  Then the title does even match the text. Closing this non-question.

Comment: ... there was a question originally (which is what I answered) ...

Answer (score 2):

I've done projects that require discrimination of long and short button presses. It's a classification problem, and in general not entirely trivial to detect unambiguously. This is, in particular, true in the presence of debounce requirements (as are present with virtually all buttons).

My recommendation would be to devote a timer interrupt to sampling the button at regular intervals (say 50ms) and stores these samples in a circular buffer (of say 25 samples, representing 1250ms worth of data). Then in your main loop, analyze the contents of that buffer to determine whether it contains a long press, a short press, or neither - and respond accordingly. You can apply whatever logic you want to filter that data as well, e.g. to apply a software debounce. If you detect an event, you should probably clear the buffer, or maybe wait for the event condition to clear the buffer before emitting another event.

I'm not going to write the code for you, but that's one approach that I've actually used.

If you have to do it purely in hardware, my answer is obviously not applicable. It's just how I would do it for flexibility's sake.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you must know before I ans this question.

1. External interrupt can be a edge or level sensitive. Read datasheet of your controller.
2. Timer 0 can be operated in gated mode that means as soon as signal appears at external interruption pin timer 0 will start running (TR0 must be equal to 1)

So you can design key interfacing in such a way that when you press key, signal goes low(which will give falling edge signal) and it can be interfaced on external interrupt pin and detected. As soon as low going signal is detected (key press is detected) timer 0 will start running. And in external interrupt ISR you can check when signal goes high that is when key is released.

Void ext_ISR()

{

while(key_press==0); //wait until signal is low

TR0 = 0; stop the time

//read the timer register and convert it into time for which timer was on i.e. Key was pressed

}

You can reduce key de-bouncing by using large capacitor connected across key.

Comment: This is very naive. You can't just connect a switch to an interrupt-triggered pin. There's no reason to add external RC filters if the programmer is competent. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32646071/slight-delay-after-returning-from-interrupt/32647699#32647699).